# Monitoring an android application

Tags: android, web-services

I need to identify how much time the webservices took in an android application.

I have an android application consuming SOAP webservices, but it takes a while to display the output.

There is fiddler to test web pages, similarly do we have something for android to test & can we see the same output in web page at the same time?

Thanks.

Comment: Can someone throw some suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Use [Traceview](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/traceview.html).